# how to JOIN table optional?

Tags: mysql

The only problem is, my code returns results only when at least one list is available in the `wp_realcustomers` table, but I want it return results whether or not it has a list/data in `wp_realcustomers`, making it some kind of optional.

Here is my code :

```
"SELECT 
    usermeta1.user_id,
    usermeta2.meta_value AS firstname,
    usermeta3.meta_value AS lastname,
    usermeta4.meta_value AS phone1,
    usermeta5.meta_value AS phone2,
    mainuser.user_email AS email,
    COUNT(customers.id) AS numberofcustomers


FROM wp_usermeta usermeta1
JOIN wp_usermeta usermeta2 ON(usermeta1.user_id = usermeta2.user_id AND usermeta2.meta_key = 'first_name' )
JOIN wp_usermeta usermeta3 ON(usermeta1.user_id = usermeta3.user_id AND usermeta3.meta_key = 'last_name' )
JOIN wp_usermeta usermeta4 ON(usermeta1.user_id = usermeta4.user_id AND usermeta4.meta_key = 'tm_phone_1' )

JOIN wp_usermeta usermeta5 ON(usermeta1.user_id = usermeta5.user_id AND usermeta5.meta_key = 'tm_phone_2' )
JOIN wp_users mainuser ON(usermeta1.user_id = mainuser.ID )
JOIN wp_realcustomers customers ON(usermeta1.user_id = customers.team_member_id )


WHERE usermeta1.meta_key='teamleader_id' && usermeta1.meta_value='1'
```

Comment: Change JOIN to LEFT JOIN (at least for the meta tables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LEFT JOIN on wp_realcustomers

```
"SELECT 
    usermeta1.user_id,
    usermeta2.meta_value AS firstname,
    usermeta3.meta_value AS lastname,
    usermeta4.meta_value AS phone1,
    usermeta5.meta_value AS phone2,
    mainuser.user_email AS email,
    COUNT(customers.id) AS numberofcustomers


FROM wp_usermeta usermeta1
JOIN wp_usermeta usermeta2 ON(usermeta1.user_id = usermeta2.user_id AND usermeta2.meta_key = 'first_name' )
JOIN wp_usermeta usermeta3 ON(usermeta1.user_id = usermeta3.user_id AND usermeta3.meta_key = 'last_name' )
JOIN wp_usermeta usermeta4 ON(usermeta1.user_id = usermeta4.user_id AND usermeta4.meta_key = 'tm_phone_1' )

JOIN wp_usermeta usermeta5 ON(usermeta1.user_id = usermeta5.user_id AND usermeta5.meta_key = 'tm_phone_2' )
JOIN wp_users mainuser ON(usermeta1.user_id = mainuser.ID )
LEFT JOIN wp_realcustomers customers ON(usermeta1.user_id = customers.team_member_id )


WHERE usermeta1.meta_key='teamleader_id' && usermeta1.meta_value='1'"
```

If You have count  you must have group by

```
"SELECT 
    usermeta1.user_id,
    usermeta2.meta_value AS firstname,
    usermeta3.meta_value AS lastname,
    usermeta4.meta_value AS phone1,
    usermeta5.meta_value AS phone2,
    mainuser.user_email AS email,
    COUNT(customers.id) AS numberofcustomers


FROM wp_usermeta usermeta1
JOIN wp_usermeta usermeta2 ON(usermeta1.user_id = usermeta2.user_id AND usermeta2.meta_key = 'first_name' )
JOIN wp_usermeta usermeta3 ON(usermeta1.user_id = usermeta3.user_id AND usermeta3.meta_key = 'last_name' )
JOIN wp_usermeta usermeta4 ON(usermeta1.user_id = usermeta4.user_id AND usermeta4.meta_key = 'tm_phone_1' )

JOIN wp_usermeta usermeta5 ON(usermeta1.user_id = usermeta5.user_id AND usermeta5.meta_key = 'tm_phone_2' )
JOIN wp_users mainuser ON(usermeta1.user_id = mainuser.ID )
LEFT JOIN wp_realcustomers customers ON(usermeta1.user_id = customers.team_member_id )


WHERE usermeta1.meta_key='teamleader_id' && usermeta1.meta_value='1'
group by  usermeta1.user_id, usermeta2.meta_value , 
          usermeta3.meta_value , usermeta4.meta_value ,
          usermeta5.meta_value , mainuser.user_email "
```

Comment: yes LEFT JOIN but COUNT is the problem here too, returns only one line (however, without COUNT, I normally get results of 2 guys, however with COUNT it returns one row counting realcustomers list of both guys 6+2 =8 ) , right now in my database table both users (Alice and Bob) are listed into wp_realcustomers table as team_member_id

Answer (score 1):

Use `left outer join` instead of `join` - more details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: I just find out that COUNT actually counting all number of customers regardless team member id, without Count line, I get return 2 rows (2 results ) Alice(6) and Bob's(2) . but when I use COUNT it gives one number of customers total 8 and one result, I need to use COUNT something different and yes , it has to be optional ofcourse.